# Transform callback approach to reactive with Combine

Tags: swift, firebase, future, combine, publisher

This is what I am doing:

-> Login/Signup to Firebase using FirebaseAuthentification

-> Listining to AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle

-> I store extra user information in Firestore, therefore I check if the user exists in Firestore

-> If the user does not exist I create an empty user

-> If everything was successful I return a Future Publisher via callback (I want to change that as well)

This is the checkLoginState function:

```
func checkLoginState(completion: @escaping (AnyPublisher<AccountDetails,Error>) -> Void) {
    self.handler = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] auth, user in
        guard let safeSelf = self else { return }
        completion(Future<AccountDetails,Error> { promise in
            if let user = user {
                print(user)
                print(auth)

                safeSelf.checkIfUserIsInDatabase(user: user.uid) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let isAvailable):
                        if isAvailable {
                             promise(.success(AccountDetails(userUID: user.uid,name: user.displayName, loggedIn: true, premiumUser: false)))
                        } else {
                            safeSelf.createEmptyUser(user: user.uid,email: user.email) { result in
                                switch result {
                                case .success(_):
                                    promise(.success(AccountDetails(userUID: user.uid,name: user.displayName, loggedIn: true, premiumUser: false)))
                                case .failure(let error):
                                    print(error)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                promise(.success(AccountDetails(userUID: nil, loggedIn: false, premiumUser: false)))
            }
            }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        )
    }
}
```

These are my current functions:

```
private func checkIfUserIsInDatabase(user id: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Bool,Error>) -> Void)

private func createEmptyUser(user id: String, email:String?, completion: @escaping (Result<Bool,Error>) -> Void)
```

Thats what I want to use:

```
private func checkIfUserIsInDatabase(user id: String) -> AnyPublisher<Bool,Error>

private func createEmptyUser(user id: String) -> AnyPublisher<Bool,Error>

func checkLoginState() -> AnyPublisher<AccountDetails,Error>
```

I had something like that, but it does not work, also looks confusing:

```
func checkLoginState(completion: @escaping (AnyPublisher<AccountDetails,Error>) -> Void) {
    self.handler = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] auth, user in
        guard let safeSelf = self else { return }
        completion(Future<AccountDetails,Error> { promise in
            if let user = user {
                print(user)
                print(auth)

                safeSelf.checkIfUserIsInDatabase(user: user.uid)
                    .sinkToResult { value in
                        switch value {
                        case .success(let isUserInDatabase):
                            if isUserInDatabase {
                                promise(.success(AccountDetails(userUID: user.uid,name: user.displayName, loggedIn: true, premiumUser: false)))
                            } else {
                                safeSelf.createEmptyUser(user: user.uid)
                                    .sinkToResult { value in
                                        switch value {
                                        case .success( _):
                                            promise(.success(AccountDetails(userUID: user.uid,name: user.displayName, loggedIn: true, premiumUser: false)))
                                        case .failure(let error):
                                            print(error)
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print(error)
                        }

                }
            } else {
                promise(.success(AccountDetails(userUID: nil, loggedIn: false, premiumUser: false)))
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the question? Is it that you don’t know how sequentialize three asynchronous operations with Combine? Or is it that you don’t know how to express an asynchronous operation as a Future? Or is it the if/then choice that your pipeline needs to make?

Comment: Yes basically I tried to use combineLatest, but I do not want them to happen at the same time, but with the result of the others

Comment: Ok cool! You’re looking for `flatMap`. Take a look at my explanation here: http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsflatmap.html#SECSerializingAsynchronicity

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/60418000/341994

Comment: What is the declaration of `addStateDidChangeListener`? Does it call its closure multiple times?

Comment: Its declaration is: " - (nonnull FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle)addAuthStateDidChangeListener:
    (nonnull FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerBlock)listener;  " it is part of the Firebase framework. It gets called whenever: " + The block is registered as a listener, + A user with a different UID from the current user has signed in, or + The current user has signed out. "

Comment: Can you also edit your question to include the definitions of `checkIfUserIsInDatabase` and `createEmptyUser`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have some `AccountDetails` type:

```
import Combine
import FirebaseAuth

struct AccountDetails {
    var userId: String
    var name: String?
    var isLoggedIn: Bool
    var isPremiumUser: Bool
}
```

Let's extend it with an `init` that takes a `User`, because it will simplify things later:

```
extension AccountDetails {
    init(user: User) {
        self.userId = user.uid
        self.name = user.displayName
        self.isLoggedIn = true
        self.isPremiumUser = false
    }
}
```

I think your end goal is a `Publisher` that emits `AccountDetails`. But since there isn't always a logged-in user, it should really emit `Optional<AccountDetails>`, so that it can emit `nil` when the user logs out.

Let's start by wrapping the `addStateDidChangeListener` API in a `Publisher`. We can't use a `Future` for this, because a `Future` emits at most one output, but `addStateDidChangeListener` can emit multiple events. So we'll use a `CurrentValueSubject` instead. That means we need a place to store the subject and the `AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle`. You could store them as globals, or in your `AppDelegate`, or wherever you feel is appropriate. For this answer, let's create a `Demo` class to hold them:

```
class Demo {
    static let shared = Demo()

    let userPublisher: AnyPublisher<User?, Error>

    private let userSubject = CurrentValueSubject<User?, Error>(nil)
    private var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []

    private init() {
        userPublisher = userSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        let handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [userSubject] (_, user) in
            userSubject.send(user)
        }
        AnyCancellable { Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle) }
            .store(in: &tickets)
    }
}
```

So now you can get a `Publisher` of the logged-in user (or nil if no user is logged in) like this:

```
let loggedInUserPublisher: AnyPublisher<User?, Error> = Demo.shared.userPublisher
```

But you really want an `AccountDetails?` publisher, not a `User?` publisher, like this:

```
let accountDetailsPublisher: AnyPublisher<AccountDetails?, Error> = Demo.shared
    .accountDetailsPublisher()
```

So we need to write an `accountDetailsPublisher` method that maps the `User?` to an `AccountDetails?`.

If the `User?` is nil, we just want to emit `nil`. But if the `User?` is `.some(user)`, we need to do more asynchronous actions: we need to check whether the user is in the database, and add the user if not. The `flatMap` operator lets you chain asynchronous actions, but there's some complexity because we need to take different actions depending on the output of the upstream publisher.

We'd really like to hide the complexity away and just write this:

```
extension Demo {
    func loggedInAccountDetailsPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<AccountDetails?, Error> {
        return userPublisher
            .flatMap(
                ifSome: { $0.accountDetailsPublisher().map { Optional.some($0) } },
                ifNone: { Just(nil).setFailureType(to: Error.self) })
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

But then we need to write `flatMap(ifSome:ifNone:)`. Here it is:

```
extension Publisher {
    func flatMap<Wrapped, Some: Publisher, None: Publisher>(
        ifSome: @escaping (Wrapped) -> Some,
        ifNone: @escaping () -> None
    ) -> AnyPublisher<Some.Output, Failure>
        where Output == Optional<Wrapped>, Some.Output == None.Output, Some.Failure == Failure, None.Failure == Failure
    {
        return self
            .flatMap { $0.map { ifSome($0).eraseToAnyPublisher() } ?? ifNone().eraseToAnyPublisher() }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Now we need to implement `accountDetailsPublisher` in a `User` extension. What does this method need to do? It needs to check whether the `User` is in the database (an asynchronous action) and, if not, add the `User` (another asynchronous action). Since we need to chain asynchronous actions, we again need `flatMap`. But we'd really like to just write this:

```
extension User {
    func accountDetailsPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<AccountDetails, Error> {
        return isInDatabasePublisher()
            .flatMap(
                ifTrue: { Just(AccountDetails(user: self)).setFailureType(to: Error.self) },
                ifFalse: { self.addToDatabase().map { AccountDetails(user: self) } })
    }
}
```

Here is `flatMap(ifTrue:ifFalse:)`:

```
extension Publisher where Output == Bool {
    func flatMap<True: Publisher, False: Publisher>(
        ifTrue: @escaping () -> True,
        ifFalse: @escaping () -> False
    ) -> AnyPublisher<True.Output, Failure>
        where True.Output == False.Output, True.Failure == Failure, False.Failure == Failure
    {
        return self
            .flatMap { return $0 ? ifTrue().eraseToAnyPublisher() : ifFalse().eraseToAnyPublisher() }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Now we need to write `isInDatabasePublisher` and `addToDatabase` methods on `User`. I don't have the source code to your `checkIfUserIsInDatabase` and `createEmptyUser` functions, so I can't convert them to publishers directly. But we can wrap them using `Future`:

```
extension User {
    func isInDatabasePublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> {
        return Future { promise in
            checkIfUserIsInDatabase(user: self.uid, completion: promise)
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func addToDatabase() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
        return Future { promise in
            createEmptyUser(user: self.uid, email: self.email, completion: promise)
        } //
            .map { _ in } // convert Bool to Void
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Note that, since your example code ignores the `Bool` output of `createEmptyUser`, I wrote `addToDatabase` to output `Void` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what I came up with:

Reference by matt:
http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsflatmap.html#SECSerializingAsynchronicity
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60418000/341994

```
 var handler: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
 var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func checkLoginState(completion: @escaping (AnyPublisher<AccountDetails,Error>) -> Void) {
        self.handler = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] auth, user in
            guard let safeSelf = self else { return }
            completion(Future<AccountDetails,Error> { promise in
                if let user = user {
                    safeSelf.handleUserInDatabase(user: user.uid)
                    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                        if let error = completion.error  {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                            promise(.failure(error))
                        }
                    }, receiveValue: { result in
                        if result {
                            promise(.success(AccountDetails(userUID: user.uid,name: user.displayName, loggedIn: true, premiumUser: false)))
                        }
                    }).store(in: &safeSelf.storage)
                } else {
                    promise(.success(AccountDetails(userUID: nil, loggedIn: false, premiumUser: false)))
                }
            }.eraseToAnyPublisher())
        }
    }


    /// Checks if User exists in Firestore, if not creates an empty User and returns true
    private func handleUserInDatabase(user: String) -> AnyPublisher<Bool,Error> {
        return Future<Bool,Error>( { [weak self] promise in
            guard let safeSelf = self else { return }
            safeSelf.checkIfUserIsInDatabase(user: user)
                .flatMap { result -> AnyPublisher<Bool,Error> in
                    if result == false {
                        return safeSelf.createEmptyUser(user: user).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    } else {
                        promise(.success(true))
                        return Empty<Bool,Error>(completeImmediately: true).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    }}
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                    if let error = completion.error {
                        promise(.failure(error))
                    }}, receiveValue: {promise(.success($0))})
                .store(in:&safeSelf.storage)
            }
        ).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```